# Did Srinivasa Ramanujan have a surviving sibling?

Tags: reference-request

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan) says 'After his death, his brother Tirunarayanan chronicled Ramanujan's remaining handwritten notes consisting of formulae on singular moduli, hypergeometric series and continued fractions and compiled them' (quoted from Indian express (I would trust not much outside The Hindu but still) and 'When Ramanujan was a year and a half old, his mother gave birth to a son, Sadagopan, who died less than three months later'. On [this site](https://www.thefamouspeople.com/profiles/srinivasa-ramanujan-503.php) 'His mother gave birth to several children after Ramanujan, but none of them survived infancy' is written. As far as I know the local folklore is Ramanujan or his immediate family had no direct descendants.

> Did Srinivasa Ramanujan have a surviving sibling?

Comment: Ramanujan was the eldest of the 5 children of K. Srinivasa Iyengar and Komalatammal. Unfortunately however, three siblings of Ramanujan died before they could even reach the age of 1 year. The youngest sibling of Ramanujan was born in 1905 and his name was Tirunarayanan. He survived till 1978. [source](https://factslegend.org/srinivasa-ramanujan-facts-55-facts-self-taught-mathematical-genius/)

Comment: 'The youngest sibling of Ramanujan was born in 1905 and his name was Tirunarayanan. He survived till 1978' (what is writer's source?) and 'His mother gave birth to several children after Ramanujan, but none of them survived infancy' are contradictory.

Answer (score 11):

There were actually *two* surviving brothers:

[image]
[source](https://www.imsc.res.in/~rao/ramanujan/newnow/familytree.htm)

See also page 12 of [Robert Kanigel's biography of Ramanujan.](https://archive.org/details/TheManWhoKnewInfinityALifeOfTheGeniusRamanujan)